# Connect Tape Drive to H330

Tags: sas, tapedrive, raid-controller

I'm re-purposing a Dell T430 server. It has an H730 connected to some disks for the OS and storage. It also has an H330, which I'm trying to use to connect an older Tandberg HH LTO4 tape drive.

Unfortunately, I'm not having much luck.

I can't see drive in Windows Device Manager at all (Server 2012 R2). There's not even anything listed under "Other Devices". Additionally, if I go into the UEFI/BIOS at startup I can get to the H330 controller configuration, but I can't find any evidence it sees the drive, either.

The drive does have power. The tape drive has both a SAS connector and an older 4-pin molex connector. If I use just the SAS connector (which does include both the data and power portions, and I can trace the power all the back to the power supply), the drive seems to not power on when I start up the machine. This power supply in this server doesn't have any molex power connectors, but if I use an adapter from a SATA power connector I can get the drive to power up when I turn on the machine. The green "ready" light blinks for a while and then turns solid.

This drive was working fine just two weeks ago, but I'm about to pull my hair out getting this server to recognize it. Any ideas?

**Update:** I've now also tried connecting directly to the S130 controller on the motherboard, using all three modes (AHCI, RAID, and ATA), and none of those modes will detect the drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never could get the H330 to use the drive, which makes me sad. But I was able to dig out an old LSI 3445E SAS controller from a retired server. That installed into the T430 just fine, and using this card I had the drive installed in Windows in less than 5 minutes.