# Identify small connectors next to SAS port on a Tape Drive

Tags: sas, connector

I'm [trying to re-purpose an old Tape Drive](https://serverfault.com/q/855856/2869), and not having much luck. As side-question to this process, the drive has two smaller connectors to the left of the normal SAS connectors, and I don't know what they are.

Picture is below, with obligatory free-hand circle:
[image: Connectors]

It's hard to see here, but the connector on top has 14 pins and the one on bottom has 4.

What are these connectors, and what are they used for?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it matters.

All that you should be concerned about for the purpose of this project is providing the 4-pin Molex port and internal cable SAS connection to the drive.

Granted, providing some info on the problem you're having would be helpful, as well as the make and model of the drive.

Comment: Let me clarify: I'm not trying to fix the tape drive in this question. I have a separate question for that (now have a link in the question here), and this question is a just a curiosity that may or may not be helpful to that one, but I'd like to know what these are either way.